# how to refresh particular element in php with jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have one select box.on change event of it, I call confirm box. When I clicked on cancel button  then remains changed value.
So I want to refresh only select box not whole page.

```
function statusChanged(obj,id){
    $(obj).change(function() {
        var answer = confirm ("Are you sure update Status?");
        var status;
        if(answer){
            status=$(this).val();
            //alert(status);
            ajaxUpdate("service-providers.php", {action:"updatestatus",'status': status,'id':id}, function(data) {
            if(data.type=="success") {
                    $("#notify").notification({caption:"Status Updated  Successfully.", type:"information", sticky:false ,onhide:function(){
                    window.location="service-providers.php";
                }
                }); 
            }
            });
        }
        else{
            // here i want to refresh select box
        }
});
}
```

html code:

```
<select id="status1" name="status1"  style="width:140px;" onChange="statusChanged(this,<?php echo $applicationid; ?>);">        
                                                    <?php
                                                        if($status==3 || $status==4)
                                                            echo "<option value='4'>Submitted</option>";
                                                        else
                                                            echo "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="2" <?php if($status==2) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Approved</option>
                                                    <option value="3" <?php if($status==3) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Rejected</option>
                                               </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code under else it will just reset select box.

This will work

```
$('#SELECTBOX_ID').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

see the for http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/10/ working demo.

also I implemented this code in my local I mainly made two changes I removed onchange from select and second is I did not use ajax coz you only want to work on click of cancel on confirm box.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function () {
         jQuery("#status1").change(function() {
         var answer = confirm ("Are you sure update Status?");
         var status;
         if(answer){
           status=$(this).val();
            //I have did not call ajax
         }
         else{
          jQuery('#status1').prop('selectedIndex',0);
         }
     });
  });
 </script>
 <?php
    $status = 0; // I temporary added t 
  ?>
  <select id="status1" name="status1"  style="width:140px;" >
  <?php
     if($status==3 || $status==4)
        echo "<option value='4'>Submitted</option>";
     else
      echo "<option value='0'>Select</option>";
    ?>
     <option value="2" <?php if($status==2) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Approved</option>
     <option value="3" <?php if($status==3) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Rejected</option>
   </select>
```

Comment: did you see demo otherwise please post your html code of selectbox

Comment: No it doesn't. It will set the first option, not the one loaded with page.
Check yourself. Your code but with selected element: http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/306/

He wants to do exacly same think as you can do on the form `$('form').reset()` but only on specified element.

Comment: ok let me try above question scenario in my local and update you soon with outcome.

Answer (score 0):

after page loads do:

```
$('select').each(function() {
 $(this).attr('original_data', $(this).val());
});
```

and in your function do

```
$(this).val(this.attr('original_data'));
```

Checked. Works perfectly.

Comment: Ok. I tried it local and it works as it should.

First you save selected data (this doesn't have to be 'select' - can be all inputs or just specified one) and save it as custom attribute.

Then you just retrieve this data whenever you need it :]